# List comprehensions in Mathematica?

Tags: list-manipulation, python

I'm looking for an implementation of list comprehensions in Python (nested `for-in` statement with destructuring and conditionals). Here's an example:

```
matrix=[['a','b'],['c','d']]
flat=[(el,i,j) for (i, array) in enumerate(matrix) for (j, el) in enumerate(array) if i!=j]
print(flat)
```

[image]

Now, anyone could write this with a table or loop, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't understand what the Python code does and, frankly, I don't really think you are providing enough info here. Can you explain what you want to do, or perhaps provide the corresponding table or loop MMA code that you mention? What functionality are you looking for exactly?

Comment: That *kind* of functionality is provided by [`Dataset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html).

Comment: @MarcoB This is probably the best/most-used feature of python. I'm just looking for an implementation of something equally useful in mma.

Comment: Well, one might say that this is not a python site, and make allowances to encourage folks who know *Mathematica* well, which is what is needed for a good answer, to try to help. After all, it's not hard to summarize the functionality in the question. Further, re "that's not what I'm looking for": what are you looking for?  The iterators in python don't have exact equivalents in *M*, however close `MapIndexed` is to `for (i, array) in enumerate(matrix)`. And since you have to use a nested loop in python, how do you expect not to have to use a loop in *M*?

Comment: Why not just `MapIndexed` with a level spec of `{2}` and a conditional `Nothing` and then call `Flatten[#, 1]` on that? Seems to me to be the easiest way.

Answer (score 16):

IMO, Mathematica's functional operators more than cover the use cases for list comprehensions in Python. There are a couple of different list comprehension syntaxes which are covered by a couple of different functions in Mathematica:

`[f(v) for v in values]` is covered by `Map[f, values]`

`[f(v, i) for v in enumerate(values)]` is covered by `MapIndexed[f, values]`

`[f(v1, v2) for v1, v2 in zip(values1, values2)]` is covered by `MapThread[f, {values1, values2}]`

The syntax `[f(v) for v in values if v == x]` is typically accomplished with `Select` or `Pick`, as in `Select[f /@ values, # == x &]`.

Python list comprehensions can also be used for nested loops:

```
[f(x, y) for x in xvalues
         for y in yvalues]
```

This is equivalent to `Flatten@Outer[f, xvalues, yvalues]`.

Mathematica's functionality in this area is much better than Python's list comprehension. Mathematica's functions are more readable and more flexible, for example in cases where you need to use the level argument.

Comment: `f/@Select[values,#==x&]` matches more closely

Comment: "Mathematica's functionality in this area is much better than Python's list comprehension" why, when, where, how?

Comment: @opisthofulax It’s not even a competition, really. For example, you can’t set the level in Python list comprehensions like you can in all the functions I mentioned above. Add to that the functions that support patterns and Mathematica simply blows Python out of the water.

Comment: This answer is so useful to me in the opposite direction, i.e. learning Python after I already know Mathematica. (I would love to see more on this. I have not been able to find a good Python for MMA programmers reference yet, see my question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/238433/resources-on-python-programming-for-mathematica-programmers.)

Answer (score 7):

Something like this?

```
matrix = {{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}};

allflat = Flatten[MapIndexed[List, matrix, {2}], 1]
(*    {{"a", {1, 1}}, {"b", {1, 2}}, {"c", {2, 1}}, {"d", {2, 2}}}    *)

flat = Select[allflat, Apply[Unequal]@*Last]
(*    {{"b", {1, 2}}, {"c", {2, 1}}}    *)
```

Comment: You can also use `Nothing` and a condition to obviate the need for the `Select` after the fact.

Answer (score 7):

A straightforward translation of a general list comprehension, suggested by various [Python tutorials](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), even if not the most efficient way (see for instance @Roman's answer), is to append each item to a list:

```
Module[{res = {}},
 MapIndexed[  (* use Do[], Map[], or MapIndexed[] to implement the iterable *)
  Function[{array, i},
   MapIndexed[
    Function[{el, j},
     If[i != j,                               (* if condition *)
      AppendTo[res, {el, First@i, First@j}]]  (* add to list *)
     ],
    array
    ]
   ],
  matrix
  ];
 res
 ]
```

`Reap` and `Sow` might be the closest thing in *Mathematica* to a list comprehension, and effectively implements the above approach.

```
Reap[
  MapIndexed[
   Function[{array, i},
    MapIndexed[
     Function[{el, j},
      If[i != j, Sow[{el, First@i, First@j}]]
      ],
     array
     ]
    ],
   matrix
   ]
  ][[2, 1]]
```

And `Reap`-`Sow` allows multiple list comprehensions simultaneously with the second *tag* argument.

Note: Sometimes one can use `Table[]` with `If[condition, x, Nothing]` to implement `[x for x in list if condition]`. But implementing nested iterations with `Table[]`, such as in the OP's example, would result in nested lists instead of a flat list.  They could be flattened.  For the OP's example:

```
Flatten[
 Table[
  With[{array = matrix[[i]]},
   Table[
    With[{el = array[[j]]},
     If[i != j, {el, i, j}, Nothing]
     ],
    {j, Length@array}
    ]
   ],
  {i, Length@matrix}
  ],
 1
 ]
```

Note that with `Table[]`, `Do[]`, and `Map[]` you can only have one item, either the index `j` or the element `el`.  If you get the index, you can extract the element as above..  To get both at once, you would have to use `MapIndexed`.  Note also that instead of `Table[]`, you can use `MapIndexed` at level 2, as in @Roman's answer, which produces a nested, non-flat, result.  Using `MapIndexed[]` instead of `Table[]` above gives us the following solution:

```
Flatten[
 MapIndexed[
  If[Unequal @@ #2, Flatten[{##}], Nothing] &, 
  matrix,
  {2}],
 1]
```

Answer (score 5):

> ...an implementation of list comprehensions in Python

We could implement Python (poorly) in *Mathematica*:

```
Needs@"GeneralUtilities`";

ClearAll[for];
SetAttributes[for, HoldAll];
for[x_ ∈ iterator_, body_] /; MatchQ[iterator, _Iterator] := 
  Module[{i, iter = iterator, tag},
   Hold[x] /. Hold[{v___}] | Hold[v___] :>
     Block[{v},    (* Blocks variables in x *)
      Reap[
        While[
         i = Read[iter];
         i =!= IteratorExhausted,
         x = i;
         Sow[body, tag]
         ],
        tag][[2, 1]]
      ]];

enumerate[list_List] := NewIterator[
   enumerate,
   {i = 0, max = Length@list},
   If[i++ < max, {i, list[[i]]}, IteratorExhausted]];

ClearAll[lc];
SetAttributes[lc, HoldAll];
lc[x_, iterFN_] := Module[{tag},
   Reap[iterFN[Unevaluated@Sow[x, tag]], tag][[2, 1]]
   ];
```

Now the syntax is pretty close to Python's:

> ```
> [
>  (el,i,j)
>  for (i, array) in enumerate(matrix) for (j, el) in enumerate(array) if i!=j
>  ]
> ```

```
lc[
 {el, i, j},
 for[{i, array} ∈ enumerate@matrix, for[{j, el} ∈ enumerate@array, If[i != j, #]]] &
 ]

(*  {{"b", 1, 2}, {"c", 2, 1}}  *)
```

One could even alter `enumerate[]` to index arrays from `0` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 4):

You can implement a do notation in Mathematica.

First, implement functions for list monad:

```
bind[fa_, f_] := Flatten[f /@ fa, 1]
return[a_] := {a}
guard[True] := {tt}
guard[False] := {}
```

And do notation:

```
do[to[x_, fa_], fb__] := bind[fa, x \[Function] do[fb]]
do[to[xs_List, fa_], fb__] := bind[fa, (xs \[Function] do[fb]) @@ # &]
do[fa_, fb__] := bind[fa, do[fb] &]
do[fa_] := fa
SetAttributes[do, HoldAll]
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
enumerate[l_] := Table[{i, l[[i]]}, {i, Length@l}]

matrix = {{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}}

do[
 {i, array}~to~enumerate[matrix],
 {j, el}~to~enumerate[array],
 guard[i != j],
 return[{el, i, j}]
 ]
```

Comment: +1. But what if someone sets `tt = Sequence[0, 1]`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 That's a problem, you can use `True` instead or protect the symbol `tt`.