# Resources on python programming for Mathematica programmers

Tags: python, reference-request

Are there any good guides to programming in python for people who are already very familiar to Mathematica. I understand that for some things the canonical python approach is different and it is good to learn that from a python guide from scratch but it would also often be useful to leverage some functional programming knowledge from Mathematica when programming in Python. It would be great if there was  a guide explaining similar data structures and functions and the differences you have to be careful with when coming from Mathematica. For example I would like to know whether there are things like pure functions, `@`,`/@`, etc., that can be used in Python.

Comment: This question seems too broad, and even if narrowed down would probably be off topic for this site.

Comment: @Jason, hmm, would you think it is more on-topic on another stackexchange? (I have some doubts it would get the right type of viewers on something more geared towards python or programmers in general.) Would the scope be better if I strictly ask for the equivalent python thing for the operations I mentioned in my post (i.e. Pure functions, @, /@, @@, @@@).

Comment: Kvothe, it might be such that no stackexchange is exactly suited for such question, and is instead a better fit on the Wolfram Community site.

Comment: It is a topic I find interesting, I would like to be able to read and really understand good python code (so I can translate it to WL).  But it doesn't fit the question/answer model of stack exchange very well.  To be fair, some of the most popular (and useful) questions on this site also don't fit that model.  I agree Wolfram Community is a better fit, though it doesn't get as much traffic.

Comment: A partial answer is provided by this answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/201440/45020. It discusses the opposite direction, i.e. coding in Mathematica when familiar with Python but the provided examples work equally well in the opposite direction.